# Import .csv file into cassandra

Tags: csv, cassandra

I want to import a CSV file into cassandra. When I write this command on cassandra cqlsh, I got an error:
command is:

```
COPY table ( ID,  name) FROM 'table.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE;
```

and the error:

```
Can't open 'table.csv' for reading: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'table.csv'
```

Can any one tell me what does it mean?

Comment: Did you run `cqlsh` in the same directory as where your 'table.csv' reside?

Comment: yes. my 'table.csv' is in cassandra/bin directory where cqlsh is. is there any deferences between windows .csv file and cassandra's? my 'table.csv' file was a export from windows mysql table.

Comment: I am saying did you run `cqlsh` in the same directory as your file? Since you are able to run `cqlsh` in directories other than `cassandra/bin`.

Comment: yes. I think I run cqlsh file in the same directiry as my .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

table.csv file should be in cassandra installation directory(where you run cqlsh).

File name is case senstive, so check with orginal file name case.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your local directory should be same and there also same file put up.

```
cqlsh.bat 192.168.1.xx -k [keyspace name] -e "COPY [domain] FROM 'filename' WITH HEADER=true"
```

Comment: How would you do if copying several columns of a file with countless of them ?

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra, It is required to mention the file name correctly (case sensitive).

use **pwd** command to know the current path in ubuntu and then give the file name.

For example if my path after executing pwd command is `/home/xyz/Docs`

Then cassandra command to copy the file is

```
COPY table ( ID,  name) FROM '/home/xyz/Docs/table.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my checklist for this error for the containerized use cases (e.g. when using `bitnami/cassandra:latest`):

1. Make sure the path you are supplying to the `COPY` command is the *internal* (container) path, not an external one (host, PVC etc).
2. Make sure the CSV file has correct read permissions for the *internal* container user ID, not the external one (host, PVC etc), especially if the CSV was created in another containerized app (e.g. Jupyter Notebook).

For example, assuming you have run your Cassandra container like this:

```
$ docker run -d --rm --name cassandra -v /tmp:/bitnami -u 1001 bitnami/cassandra:4.0
```

Then the `COPY` command issued in `cqlsh` to import a `/tmp/random_data1.csv` from the host should be:

```
> COPY dicts.dict1 (key, value) FROM '/bitnami/random_data1.csv' WITH HEADER = true;
```

and the `/tmp/random_data1.csv` file should be owned by user 1001 or accessible for reading for all users.